# How to change WPF DataGrid cell widget background color according to cell background color?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, datagrid

### The background

I use VS2010, DataGrid (the one delivered with WPF) and I manually create rows and columns. I set various colors for rows, depending of their state (but for simplicity let's say it was yellow). It worked because datagrid used labels for displaying text, and when I set background for row, it is reflected in label widget as well.

However, I couldn't ctrl+c (copy) content of the cell, so now I create custom template for columns and I use textbox to show the data.

### The problem

Texbox blocks background of the cells, so in effect I get (for example) datagrid with white cells (textboxes) with yellow borders.

### The question

How to make textboxes (this is my case) be aware of the background color of the cells? I tried to use a trick and set transparent brush for all textboxes but I still get white background in cells (textboxes).

Current code:

```
        grid.BeginInit();
        grid.Columns.Clear();


        int i = 0;
        
        var glass_brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,0,0,0));

        foreach (var db_col in query.FieldNames)
        {
            var template = new DataTemplate();
            var elemFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
            elemFactory.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding(String.Format("Visual[{0}]", i)));
            // make the background transparent -- it does not work though
            elemFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty,glass_brush);
            template.VisualTree = elemFactory;

            var col = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
            col.CellTemplate = template;
            col.IsReadOnly = true;
            col.Header = db_col;
            grid.Columns.Add(col);
            ++i;
        }

        {
            grid.Items.Clear();


            foreach (var db_row in diffs)
            {
                var row = new DataGridRow();
                row.Item = db_row.Item1;
                row.Background = colors[db_row.Item2];
                grid.Items.Add(row);
            }
        }
        grid.IsReadOnly = true;

        grid.EndInit();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting `TextBlock.BackgroundProperty`, which is based on `TextElement.BackgroundProperty`, instead of setting `TextBox.BackgroundProperty` or `Control.BackgroundProperty`, which is based on `Panel.BackgroundProperty`.  Also, your `glass_brush` is an opaque black brush instead of a transparent one.  You can use `Brushes.Transparent`.  Try:

```
elemFactory.SetValue(Control.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Transparent);
```

Comment: Stupid, stupid typo! I say there is too many dynamic pieces in supposedly static language, if not this I would hit it -- I tried of course 0 for alpha channel as well. Nevertheless your solution is very elegant (lesson for me: using basic control properties, instead of targer, to avoid typo again) -- thank you very much!